# How do I filter and substitue TextBox characters during input in VB.net 2005

Tags: vb.net, windows-ce

I have two textBox input fields that must be numeric only, limited to 7 digits. However, the target device has a tiny keyboard with a shared numeric keypad that is accessible via a numlock key, so the key 'E' doubles as the '1'.  The problem is that with the numlock enabled the backspace/del key does not work so input is difficult... fat fingers constantly pushing the wrong key, etc...

So what I would like to do is automatically convert 'E' to '1', 'R' to '2', etc, as I type. I don't want to see 'E' then '1', it has to look just like the numlock is pressed.  It also has to accept 0..9 if the numlock is pressed.

Substitute these characters: "ertdfgxcvERTDFGXCV0123456789" 
for these: "012345678901234567890123456789"

Is there an easy way to do this in VB.net-2005 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this event;

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    For Each c As Char In "ertdfgxcvERTDFGXCV"
        If e.KeyChar = c Then
            e.KeyChar = Chr(48 + counter)
        End If
        counter += 1
        If counter = 10 Then counter = 0
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Well, I tried this in VB 2005 and e.KeyChar is ReadOnly so it won't work.  I tried it in VB 2008 and it worked.  Unfortunately my application is in VB 2005.